# Expire page cache after certain interval of time asp.net 2.0 C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, caching, browser-cache

I have an application built on `asp.net 2.0 (C#)` and what I am trying to do is `clear the browser cache after certain interval of time`. Suppose, the landing page of the application is A.aspx and the user navigates to some other page B.aspx from A.aspx and then if the user `clicks back button from the browser` to go back to A.aspx `within 10mins`, I want the `page to load from the cache` but if the user tries to navigate to page A.aspx `after 10mins`, then I want the `page to load from the server or some other link` from the application. How can I `acheieve this across all browsers`?

I tried by setting:

`Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("must-revalidate");
 Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("max-age=120");` 
with `partial success in Internet Explorer` but `not with other browsers`.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: What is with the random use of markdown?

Comment: The markdown was to highlight the key points, which might seem random to individuals. Would appreciate your help if you can guide me to the solution of the question instead of commenting on the markdowns! Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y18he7cw(v=vs.140).aspx)?

Comment: Yes but didn't help!